# Consistent ways of memorizing one dimensional information in 24 bit color

Tags: image, matlab, opencv, colors

Say that I have a scalar information assigned to every pixel of a `2D` rectangle `R`, e.g. a grayscale image, or a depth-map/bump-map.

[image]

Such a scalar information is canonically encoded in a `8 bit` image, which allows `2^8=256` different tones. Conveniently, tones here have a pretty **intuitive meaning**, e.g. `white=0`, `black=1`, `gray=somewhere between 0 and 1`.

Once the image is saved, e.g. in .png, the tone `t`, `0 <= t <= 255`, is encoded in the `RGB` color `[t,t,t]` (which wastes `16bit` per pixel).

---

**Question:**
Say, that the resolution provided by the `8 bit` grayscale is not enough for my purpose.

Are there established ways to losslessly encode a `24bit` (1D) information to the `RGB` color space preserving some **intuitive meaning** of colors?

Comment: RGB handles 24-bit info pretty intuitively. Your task is to just assign meaning of each colour to your data. For example colour is excellent at intuitively representing 3D directional data. So it's pretty specific on what your data represents. Also I don't think .png wastes 16bit per pixel, I'm pretty sure it uses a colour map instead of a 3 digit vector per pixel.

Comment: @Dan, agree. So, let me rephrase a little bit. Can some kind of intuitive ordering be introduced in the RGB color space to represent a 1D (i.e. non vector) information. Can I gain at least some bit?

Comment: @Acorbe: No, I don't believe there's any curve through every point in the entire 3D colour-space which would result in a pleasing, meaningful (to a human eye) 1D spectrum.

Comment: But then your question is how to arrange your 1D data in 3D. So basically you just want to fold it up. It's only as intuitive as you make it - it certainly won't be universally intuitive but it you could probably learn an to an intuition about some arrangement. Can't you just go with 24 bit greyscale? For display purposes you (as a human) won't be able to distinguish that sort of resolution anyway, colour or not. So even if a screen can't display a 24bit grey scale image, there is nothing stopping matlab holding 24bit data per pixel of a 2D matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to consider a [Hilbert curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve). This is an embedding of a one-dimensional curve into a higher dimensional (2, 3 or more) space.

Here's what it might look like in the case of mapping a 1d curve into a two-dimensional colour space. The white curve has 2^16 = 65,536 points, and is embedded into a 2^8 x 2^8 = 256 x 256 dimensional colour space. Any two neighbouring points on the curve are very similar.

It's possible to generalize this to embed a curve into three dimensions, though I haven't got the code to hand. I can make the Matlab code that generates this plot available if you like, though I'm not convinced it will be very helpful...

[image]

This is the color scale you end up with by following the Hilbert curve through the image. Not super intuitive, but it does cover all 65,536 colors.

[image]

**Edit** - here's the code

```
function [x,y] = d2xy(n,d)
# D2XY Embeds a point d into an n*n square (assuming n is a power of 2). For
# example, if n = 8 then we can embed the points d = 0:63 into it.
    x = uint32(0);
    y = uint32(0);
    t = uint32(d);
    n = uint32(n);
    s = uint32(1);
    while s < n
        rx = bitand(1, idivide(t, 2));
        ry = bitand(1, bitxor(t,rx));
        [x,y] = rot(s,x,y,rx,ry);
        x = x + s * rx;
        y = y + s * ry;
        t = idivide(t, 4);
        s = s * 2;
    end
end

function [x,y] = rot(n,x,y,rx,ry)
    if ry == 0
        if rx == 1
            x = n-1-x;
            y = n-1-y;
        end
        # Swap x and y
        t = x; x = y; y = t;
    end
end

b = zeros(65536, 2);

for d = 0:65535
  [x,y] = d2xy(256, d);
  b(d+1,1) = x;
  b(d+1,2) = y;
end

plot(b(:,1), b(:,2)), xlim([-1,256]), ylim([-1,256]), axis square
```

Comment: this is definitely nice! Is it handy for you to post also the ordered (1D) color scale? thanks

Comment: But be careful, although neighbouring points will be of a similar colour, some very distant points will also be a similar colour. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Hilbert3d-step3.png notice how the red and green are in neighbouring voxels, if you had used that over a 3D colour space those points would be nearly the same colour but actually very distant from each other in your original 1D space.

Comment: @Dan Yes, you're right. You can see that in the 1D colour scale that I just edited to include. Mostly this was an excuse for me to write some code to generate a Hilbert curve, which I've been meaning to do for a while :)

Comment: @ChrisTaylor, since the problem is ill-posed and doesn't have a proper solution, I am happy to accept this one. I really do like the idea.. BTW, I enjoyed your talk about type algebra..

Answer (score 0):

HSV or HSI color space is the exactly what you are looking for:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html
HSI means hue, saturation and illumination or intensity. Hue gives the color frequency and it is quite intuitive to represent colors

Comment: HSV may be more intuitive than RGB in some circumstances (i.e. when colour actually represents colour) but it certainly doesn't help convert a 24bit 1D vector to a 24bit 3D vector with only 8 bits per channel.

Comment: it does not seem possible to encode color pace information just to 8 bits (except clustering) and 16 bits per pixel is not wasted in this regard

Answer (score 0):

I think you could quantize to 8, i.e. distribute intensity / 8 to as equal to 3 colors (you get a grey) and add the remaining bits (intensity % 8) to LSB of separed R,G,B. We can do with a local addition. Something like (untested but compiled)

```
int convert(int N) {

    int Q = N / 8,  //  Q + Z == N
        Z = N % 8;

    int R = (Q >>  0) & 0xFF,
        G = (Q >>  8) & 0xFF,
        B = (Q >> 16) & 0xFF,
        S = R + ((Z >> 0) & 1),
        H = G + ((Z >> 1) & 1),
        C = B + ((Z >> 2) & 1);

    return (S << 0) + (H << 8) + (C << 16);
}
```